# Previewing a website before changing ns record to an active domain

Tags: migration, hosts

How can I preview a website located on server X while the active domain is on server Y?
I just want to make sure that the migration is successful before changing the ns records.

I've heard that it's about changing the host file(?).
If so, what should I do afterwards?

I'm on mintLinux.

Thanks,
Artas

Comment: Press F5. :P The file is `/etc/hosts`, by the way.

Comment: while waiting for a reply here I've figured out how to change the file hosts, save and refresh ;-) Thanks for the answer though ;-)

Comment: That’s great. You can answer your own question and, after a certain time has passed, accept your own answer. This helps keep [su] clean.